# Spinner first element height is not setting to zero

Tags: android, height, spinner, dropdown

I want to make spinner with hint, following one of the solutions I'm making first element of drop down list height to 0, but it is ignored and first element is still visible and has height > 0.
Code:

```
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item) {

            @Override
            public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
                View v =  super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = v.getLayoutParams();
                v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (position == 0) {
                    lp.height = 0; //doesn't affect anything
                } else {
                    lp.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                }
                v.setLayoutParams(lp);
                return v;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isEnabled(int position){
                return position != 0;
            }
        };
        spinnerAdapter.add(getHint());
        spinnerAdapter.addAll(getItems());
        spinnerView.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

When I try to set `height = 1` it works and item gets almost disappeared, but that's not exactly how it should work. 
Is there a reason why that could happen? Are there any ways to set height exactly to zero?

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom adapter for spinner and change your code like this also add position control

```
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = flater.inflate(R.layout.list_itemslayout,parent, false);
        }
        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());
        return convertView;
    }
```